# Msbuild cyrillic output is not properly displayed in git bash mintty on Windows

Tags: git, msbuild, git-bash, cyrillic

In git bash `mintty 2.8.4 (x86_64-pc-msys)` I run this command:

```
'/c/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe' src\\myproj.sln /target:Build /property:Configuration=Release
```

The output prints English characters but all Russian ones are replaced with some artifact character:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine ▒▒▒ᨨ 12.0.40629.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework ▒▒▒ᨨ 4.0.30319.42000]
(C) ▒▒௮▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ (Microsoft Corporation). ▒▒ ▒ࠢ▒ ▒▒▒饭▒.

▒▒▒ઠ ▒஥▒⮢ ▒ ▒⮬ ▒襭▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒. ▒⮡▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ࠫ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ᡮ▒▒, ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ࠬ▒▒▒ "/m".
▒▒▒ઠ ▒▒▒▒ 16.06.2018 10:30:42.
ClCompile:
  ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒室▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒ॡ▒▒▒▒.
  ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒室▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒ॡ▒▒▒▒.
  ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒室▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒ॡ▒▒▒▒.
Link:
  ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒室▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒ॡ▒▒▒▒.
```

Git: `git version 2.16.2.windows.1`

```
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Windows 7 x64 Russian

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your CMD windows font to [Lucida Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida#Lucida_Console).

That font supports the [WGL4 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Glyph_List_4), which includes Cyrillic.

In that console, for testing, type:

```
set LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

And then try a `git` command.

Comment: It was set to Lucida Console by default. I also tried several other fonts but it didn't help(including setting the LC_ALL)